# locaforage getItem() is not executing

Tags: angularjs, localforage

```
$localForage.getItem('brandChainNames', function(err, data) {
    // The same code, but using ES6 Promises.
    console.log('_storedValue: '+ data);
});
```

There is no key so far (verified in tools-> storage perspective). But that console output does not print anything (in firefox). Could someone tell me what could be the problem. console output before and after it, prints fine.

EDIT:
modified the code like:

```
var hallabolo = $localForage.getItem('brandChainNames', function(err, data) {
    // The same code, but using ES6 Promises.
    console.log('_storedValue: '+ data);
});
```

angular.toJson(hallabolo) prints `{}`
tried with:
1.`JSON.stringify(hallabolo)=='{}'`// returns false
2.`Object.keys(hallabolo).length` // returns 1
3. `jQuery.isEmptyObject(hallabolo)`// returns false
4. `angular.isObject(hallabolo)`// returns true

Not to mention `type of 'undefined'`, null etc does not work as hallabolo is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$localForage.getItem('brandChainNames', function(err, data) {
    // The same code, but using ES6 Promises.
    console.log('_storedValue: '+ data);
});
```

is not working but following is working:

```
$localForage.getItem('brandChainNames').then(function(data) {
    // The same code, but using ES6 Promises.
    console.log('_storedValue: '+ data);// data is printed as undefined, as expected
});
```

Anyone, why?